# If I can prove $Y$ from "$X$ is true" and from "$X$ is false", can I prove $Y$ without using $X$ at all?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy, proof-theory, formal-proofs

Suppose I have a statement $X$, for which I do not know whether it is true or false. And suppose further that I want to prove a statement $Y$:

- I first assume that $X$ is *true*, and I construct an involved argument that shows that $Y$ follows.
- I then assume that $X$ is *false*, and another involved argument shows that $Y$ still follows.

I have then proven $Y$ (assuming excluded middle). Now, is there any kind of meta-theorem in mathematics that tells me that there should be a proof of $Y$ that is *not* mentioning $X$ at all (whatever that means formally)?

You can think about this as follows:

> Was it necessary to have formulated $X$ in order to give a proof for $Y$, or could we have proven $Y$ right away without the "halt in between"?

For example, the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Excluded_middle) seems to be such an important "halt in the middle" for some statements.

I know, this is a rather informal question.
I do not want to formulate it in terms of mathematical logic and proof theory, simply beacuse I do not know enough about these subjects.
Maybe the question has a trivial counterexample if we go formal enough.
But then again, maybe someone with enough knowledge still sees an interesting variant of the question.
I am also happy to receive quite technical answers.

Comment: This seems quite similar to [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) and it's variances.

Comment: Isn't this just a "Proof by Cases"? $A \lor B \implies C$ where in this case it's $A \lor \lnot A \implies B$?

Comment: @M.Winter Formally I can't say, but practically it's commonplace to use this technique. You want to prove $Y$. To get there you assume first $X$, and do your arithmetical manpulation and prove $Y$. Then you assume $\lnot X$ and again, do your thing and get $Y$. Hence $Y$ is proven, and is in fact independent of $X$. But in order to get to $Y$, you *specifically use* as a springboard $X$, and then again $\lnot X$. "First assume $n$ even. ... Now assume $n$ odd ..." It's what we do, and it's how we work.

Comment: You say 'assuming the law of excluded middle', and I think that provides a pointer in a way: Any such proof of $Y$ is going to need to use excluded middle in _some_ fashion, as such a proof of $Y$ doesn't need to be constructively valid and so we can 'prove' some $Y$ this way that are classically true and constructively false...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I understand that with or without "excluded middle" makes a big difference. But I do not want to get rid of excluded middle. I just want to get rid of applying excluded middle at $X$, and I am aware that this is terribly ill-defined. But I currently have no better way of phrasing my wondering about such "intermediate statements", the truth of which is completely irrelevant, but they are nevertheless unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Lets give a minimal formalization in Gentzen style proof systems:
Assume $X \Rightarrow Y$ and $\neg X \Rightarrow Y$. From these two we can deduce $X \lor \neg X \Rightarrow  Y$ (1). On the other hand, in classical mathematics, we have $\Rightarrow  X \lor \neg X$ (2). You proved your statement by using a cut rule on (1) and (2). Gerhard Gentzen's  main result was [cut elimination theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) for his system.
So your question can be reformulated in this formalism as "Is cut rule always eliminable?"
For some logics and theories it is proved. But generally speaking, it is not answered and "hardly seems possible".

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say about what does a proof "contains" in here, indeed if $T∪\{a\}⊢x$ and $T∪\{¬a\}⊢x$ then $T⊢x$ because in any model of $T$ either $a$ or $¬a$ are true, hence $T⊨x⇒T⊢x$, but how do you define "not mentioning"?

One interpretation you can think of is if $a$ is not in the language of $T$, that is:

Given a theory $T$ in the language $\cal{L}$, and given a language $\cal{L}'\supset\cal{L}$, is it possible to have a formula $a$ in the language of $\cal{L}'$ such that $T∪\{a\}⊢_{\cal{L}'}x$ and $T∪\{¬a\}⊢_{\cal{L}'}x$ and $T⊢_{\cal{L}}x$ is false?

***In this interpretation the answer is false:

Let $\cal{L}$ be empty and $\{f,g\}=\cal{L}'$ be 1-ary functional symbols, and let $a$ be the following theory:

$$(f\text{ is injective}∧f\text{ is not surjective})∧(g\text{ is injective}∧g\text{ is surjective})$$
And let $x$ be:
$$∃z,y\ (z≠y)$$

Notice that $a$ does prove $x$, as well as $¬a$ proves $x$, but $x$ is not tautology.***

***As Noah said, this example is wrong, $¬a$ does not prove $x$.

Although the above answer is wrong, I leave this post up and not deleting it because it is yet another possible interpretation of the question.

Comment: Your example doesn't work: $\neg a$ does **not** prove $x$. (Also in the statement of $x$ you've used "$x$" where I think "$z$" was meant.) The negation of $a$ says that *either* $f$ is non-injective *or* $f$ is surjective *or* $g$ is non-injective *or* $g$ is non-surjective. The second clause is trivially satisfied in every one-element structure. So $\neg a$ is compatible with $x$ being false. Indeed, the answer to your interpretation of the question is **no** (this is easiest to see if you think in terms of $\models$, in my opinion).

Comment: @NoahSchweber you are correct, I had a brainfart, sorry.

Answer (score -3):

**Proposition:** The set $c\mathbb R = \{cx : x\in\mathbb R\}$ is closed.

You can prove this if you assume $c=0,$ and also if you assume $c\ne0.$ But I will be surprised if you can do it without considering those two cases.

Comment: I have not downvoted, but I am not quite sure that this is what I meant. Your $Y$ should actually  be "**for all** $c$ holds ... is closed". Assuming $X\equiv c=0$ or its convese makes then no sense. Also, I am not sure whether I can be convinced by such examples, because there might be an unnecessarily complicated prove that we just don't see right now. Maybe we can show $x\mapsto cx$ is a closed map without using $c=0$ or $c\not=0$.